# Order By field where longest string comes first

Tags: java, mysql, csv, collation

#### Setup

I have three mysql tables, 'course','section',and 'time_slot'. Periodically I update these tables based off of a CSV data file which comes in a denormalized form. i.e.

```
--------------------------------------------------
| subject | number | section | days | start_time |
--------------------------------------------------
| EDSC    | 209    | A       | M    | 8:00       |
--------------------------------------------------
| EDSC    | 209    | A       | TR   | 8:00       |
--------------------------------------------------
| EDSC    | 209    | A       | T    | 8:00       |
--------------------------------------------------
etc...
```

*Note: the reason these seem to be overlapping is because they can happen on different dates, however this is irrelevant for this question*

Notice that they are sorted by day of week, and **multi-day entries come before single day**

I have this sql query that attempts to match the format of the CSV, then programmatically, I check for updates, adds, deletes, etc.  My algorithm relies on them being in the correct order.

```
SELECT 
    c.subject, c.course_number, s.section_name, 
    t.days, t.start_time, t.end_time, t.building, t.room
FROM section s
JOIN course c on c.id=s.course_id
LEFT JOIN time_slot t on t.section_id=s.id
ORDER BY c.subject, c.course_number, s.section_name, t.start_time, t.days;
```

This produces the following output

```
--------------------------------------------------
| subject | number | section | days | start_time |
--------------------------------------------------
| EDSC    | 209    | A       | 1    | 8:00       |
--------------------------------------------------
| EDSC    | 209    | A       | 2    | 8:00       |
--------------------------------------------------
| EDSC    | 209    | A       | 2,4  | 8:00       |
--------------------------------------------------
etc...
```

*Note, I used numbers as days to making ordering possible without adding a custom collation, and convert the CSV days to numbers in code*

Question: Is there a way to order by a field where longest strings come first?  I looked into LENGTH(t.days) DESC, but I also need M to come before TR.

Comment: If your app works, then perhaps you shouldn't worry about changing it.  If you wrap all the changes in a single transaction, you won't even see the delete and subsequent insert.

Comment: you can put several fields in the order clause: `ORDER BY t.days ASC, LENGTH(t.days) DESC`

Comment: @Bulat I just tried that, but it seems that only the first ORDER BY clause takes effect.  The second part only affects records that are considered equal in the first part.  In this case, "1" is considered less than "1,2", so the length ordering does not get applied.

Comment: You question would be better if you remove questions sections and only leave the first question that is relevant to the title. Questions 2,3 are not relevant / complete and should be asked as separate questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick and durty solution for ordering part of the question will be to append 'ZZZZZZ' string to the field in the order clause:

```
...
ORDER BY t.days || 'ZZZZZZ' ASC
...
```

This way shorter strings will be pushed to the bottom in the results while preserving the order for the first characters.

Just need to make sure that 'ZZZ' string is long enough and Z is actually the last char in your domain.

**Explanation**
If you had two values 'A' and 'AA' and your goal is to get the following order:

- AA
- A

If you just order by a field you get:

- A
- AA

This is because absent char is less than any other char for sorting function.

So you need to replace absent char by the last char to fix that, adding 'ZZZZ' is doing just that, and results in:

- AAZZZZ
- AZZZZ

Comment: This does it, but I don't understand how it works.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: Wow, that's pretty nifty, and doesn't introduce anything weird into my actual data, just an extra clause in the query.  Thank you.